# How to apply kenburnseffect into crossplatform xamarin imageview?

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am working in the xamarin mobile application. I have to design and apply the ken burns effect in the header image. I am searching till now and not get any solution? Kindly help me, anyone.  Thanks.

Comment: By I search, I just find a way to use kenburnview in Android, don't find a way to use it in Xamarin.forms

Comment: yes.. is this possible to apply in xamarin or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply kenburneffect in xamarin.android, you can take a look the following steps:

Firstly, you need to install **Xamarin.kenBurnsView**,then use this in android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView 
    android:id="@+id/kenBurnsView1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/a11" />
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="resume" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="pause" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {        

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout12);


        var kenburnimage = FindViewById<KenBurnsView>(Resource.Id.kenBurnsView1);
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1).Click += delegate { kenburnimage.Resume(); };

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2).Click += delegate { kenburnimage.Pause(); };


    }
```

[image]

Comment: i need to integrate kenburneffect both android and ios in xamarin forms.